# Jest with amCharts4 in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, amcharts, amcharts4

Test cases are failing for the components using `amcharts4`.
I've tried using

```
"jest": {
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(@amcharts)\\/).+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$"
],}
```

but this did not resolve the issue.
The documentation of `amCharts` mentioned that it can be resolved using `jest` with `puppeteer`.
Does anybody know any other workaround to this problem? Using `jest` with `puppeteer` is the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add the below code in `jest` config and also if you are using `mount/shallow` for testing then move to `ReactDOM.render()` as `jest` does not support testing `SVG` and `amCharts` use `SVG` internally.

```
"jest": {
 "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules[/\\\\](?!@amcharts[/\\\\]amcharts4)"
 ]
}
```